# Is console logging inappropriate for chatty applications?

Tags: architecture, programming-practices, performance, logging

[12 Factor](http://12factor.net/logs) states that applications should log to the console, those console logs should should be unbuffered, and the logs should be redirected to someplace useful (file, database, whatever).

But writing unbuffered data to anywhere is extremely slow.

Does this mean that 12 Factor is inappropriate when an application is doing a lot of logging (for example, due to regulatory requirements)?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog)**

Comment: @gnat I don't think that applies. Going through the points in order: 1) I'm not looking for a discussion; 2) I hope the answers will not be opinion-based, but rather be action-based (e.g., "The most common way we handle this in 12F apps is X"); 3) The source material is pretty specific and concise; 4) I don't think I'm unclear about the problem, but to clarify I'm concerned about the performance implications of unbuffered console logging

Comment: as far as I can tell, question lacks an explanation for their preference (unbuffered stdout). That makes it look like pulled out of thin air and opens the door for purely opinionated (but legitimate, in the context of the question) answers... "Oh they just don't understand and give wrong advice" or, "They advice because they know much better, their way is the only way to go" etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood the recommendations for logging.

The 12 Factor site states

> A twelve-factor app never concerns itself with routing or storage of its output stream. It should not attempt to write to or manage logfiles. Instead, each running process writes its event stream, unbuffered, to `stdout`. During local development, the developer will view this stream in the foreground of their terminal to observe the app’s behavior.

Unless you configure your environment otherwise, `stdout` *will be* buffered. Specifically, the runtime environment standard performs line-buffering on `stdout`.

What I believe is meant by 12 Factors is that the application should not concern itself with this buffering and particularly not implement additional buffering above what the environment does for you.

Comment: Ah okay, I interpreted this to mean that the application should take steps to ensure that the output is unbuffered (e.g., by writing std::endl in C++ or passing the -u flag to python).